# List result of lookup A in B, B in C without helper column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 tables:

Table1 containing Customer & Part#
Table2 containing Part# & Type

(The actual data lists are larger)

**Table1** (Customer & Part#) & Table3 (Helper):

| Customer | Part# | *Helper* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | *X* |
| B | 2 | *Y* |
| C | 3 | *X* |
| A | 4 | *Y* |
| A | 5 | *X* |
| A | 5 | *X* |
| A | 2 | *Y* |

**Table2**:

| Part# | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X |
| 2 | Y |
| 3 | X |
| 4 | Y |
| 5 | X |

Desired result for combination of customer `A` and Type `X`:

| Part# |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 5 |
| 5 |

These being the 3 results of part numbers in Table1 that are Customer A and the lookup of the Part# results in Type X (see also Helper column).

I'm able to retrieve the results by creating the helper column as shown in the example data, however I want to skip this column and solve it in one go. But I don't know if that's even possible.

I was thinking about something in this direction.. `=INDEX (Table1[Part'#],IF(Table1[Customer]="A",ROW(Table1[Customer]))`
..but there I get stuck. I think I can pickup from there with IF, ISNUMBER, SEARCH but my head errors there.

Does anybody know a way to skip the helper column for this?

PS I have office365, but FILTER is not yet released by company rules (unfortunately).

PS I prefer a formula solution, but VBA is allowed when necessary

Comment: Have you tried with Excel `ISEVEN` and `ISODD` functions. Does this work in your case. [Even Or Odd Numbers In Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/929-excel-filter-even-odd-numbers.html) or your reference Col is `Customer` rather than `part#`

Comment: Never seen it, but it is active in the Excel version we have. Not sure what's the use of it in this case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formula solution for Excel version 2010 to 2019

In `I3`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A$3:A$9)/(VLOOKUP(N(IF({1},B$3:B$9)),D$3:E$7,2,0)=H$3)/(A$3:A$10=G$3),ROW(A1))),"")
```

[image]